# Throwing an exception from Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I want to throw a `ContentIOException` from a method whose signature look like this.

```
public void putContent(InputStream is) throws ContentIOException.
```

When I try to throw `ContentIOException` from Mockito like such:

```
when(StubbedObject.putContent(contentStream)).thenThrow(ContentIOException.class);
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
The method when(T) in the type Mockito is not applicable for the arguments (void).
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using PowerMock? Since Mockito can't mock final and static methods

Comment: I went ahead and removed the final modifier for you @EugenMartynov

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Take a look at [this reference in the official API](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doThrow(java.lang.Throwable)).  You want to reverse the way your call is made and adjust the argument too, since this is a `void` method that you expect to throw an exception.

```
doThrow(new ContentIOException()).when(StubbedObject).putContent(contentStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
    when(testRepositoryMock.findOne(123)).thenThrow(new NullPointerException());
```

Then after you can check your logic

```
        String erroResponse= service.testMethodForResponse(accountNum);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(erroResponse);
         String _acNo = jsonObj.getString("accountNum");
        assertEquals(accountNum, _acNo);
        }
```

If you are using Spring boot then add top of class

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Inside of class you need to inject object

```
@InjectMocks //actual object you want to get test coverage
private TestService testService;
@Mock //Mock object which call by actual object for mocking
private testRepository testRepositoryMock;
```

Reference link :http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-behavior